# Human friendly trim of a string

Tags: elixir

I want to trim a string in a human friendly way.

```
foobar="John Doe - CEO @ xyz"

def human_trim(input, length) do
  ...
end
```

When `human_trim(foobar, 10)` the output should be `John Doe`. `human_trim(foobar, 7)` should result in `John`. So splitting by space and than check what fits until the 10 characters are reached. The edge case would be a string with no spaces at all. Than it would have to cut at -3 and add '...' at the end.

I can figure out a way to solve this problem with a million of if/else. But I struggle to find a clean way which solves this recursively. Elixir style.

What is the cleanest way to solve this?

Bonus-Question: Is the cleanest also the most performant solution?

Comment: What is the point in splitting by space if you want the space in the output?

Comment: @JustinWood I don't have real estate to display more than x characters but I want it to be human friendly.

Comment: What is the use case for something like this? Is it for a website? Console application? Something else? There may be a better solution for what you are attempting to do.

Comment: @JustinWood Display a string on a website. Plus learning from it.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Instead of complex function for both cases consider two functions- one for first name and one for full name. Don't mix them, because you would have something very ugly.

Comment: I'm not talking about names only. This is just an example. Take any random sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution. It might need some polish, but should guide you:

```
def human_trim(input, length) do
  input
  |> String.split
  |> fill_to(length)
end

defp fill_to(word_list, length) do
  fill_to(word_list, length, {[], 0})
end

defp fill_to([head|[]], length, {[], _}) do
  String.slice(head, 0..(length - 1)) <> "..."
end

defp fill_to([head|tail], length, {str, cur_length}) do
  new_length = cur_length + String.length(head)

  if new_length >= length do
    Enum.join(str, " ")
  else
    fill_to(tail, length, {str ++ [head], new_length})
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your comments of needing this for a website. Your best option will be to use CSS to display the first part of the string for you.

```html
<style>
  p {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
</style>    

<p>
  This is some long text that needs to be trimmed
</p>
```

This will limit the amount of characters that can be seen based on the width of the outer div

- `text-overflow: ellipsis;` will make sure that an ellipsis will be shown if there is too much text to fit in the given space
- `overflow: hidden;` will make sure that whatever cannot fit within the width will not be shown
- `width: 100px;` is just limiting the amount of space for the purposes of this demo
- `white-space: nowrap;` will make sure that the text is not wrapped if you do not specify a max height.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2sawd0L2/) to see.

Comment: I don't have the luxury to solve this with CSS. I have to solve it on the server.

Comment: You asked about the cleanest and most performant solution. This is it. The main issue about displaying this on a website is that you cannot guarantee that the amount of information you send the client will actually fit in the space provided. For example, 'l' takes up less space than 'm'. The exception to this rule is if you are using a monospaced font.